# Simple React Component State, setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

I've read through a lot of these solutions on Stack Overflow but am still at a total loss on why exactly this is happening and how to solve this.

I have my Chart component, which is rendered the the page, component is mounted. As I mouse over my Chart values (onValueMouseOver), that is when I get the error. I just don't understand how my component is considered not mounted if I'm able to mouse over it.

I've tried creating a separate `this.mounted` variable that I set to true/false dependent on `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and only using `setState` when these are true. The below code outputs "mounting" message (never an "unmounting" one), but the value "true" it outputted to the console upon startup, I'm assuming since I bound those methods in the constructor. But when I mouse over, "false" is logged. It doesn't log an error, but still doesn't set the value, which I need it to do.

Any help would be appreciated in directing me toward the "right way" to handle this situation. I've been using this exact method in several places and they all used to work before I updated some of my libs and webpack configuration.

Here's my code. I'm using [react-vis](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/).

```
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mounted = false;
    this.state = {
      value: null
    };
    this.rememberValue = this.rememberValue.bind(this);
    this.forgetValue = this.forgetValue.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('mounting');
    this.mounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('unmounting');
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  rememberValue(value) {
    console.log(this.mounted);
    if (this.mounted) {
      this.setState({value});
    }
  }

  forgetValue() {
    console.log(this.mounted);
    if (this.mounted) {
      this.setState({
        value: null
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { series } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <XYPlot />
        <LineMarkSeries
          data={series.data}
          onValueMouseOver={this.rememberValue}
          onValueMouseOut={this.forgetValue}
        />
        <XAxis />
        <YAxis />
        {value && <Hint value={value} {...this.props} />}
      </XYPlot>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your if condition in `forgetValue` supposed to be `!this.mounted`? That's a event handler that can call `setState` when you set `this.mounted` as false.

Comment: Oops. No. Typo on my part. Updating...

Comment: Try changing your `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount` and remove your `this.mounted` assignment out of your `constructor`. `componentWillMount` can give unexpected behavior and will actually be depreciated in React +17

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on behavior. MouseOver event just logs that `this.mounted = undefined` with the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omar's solution is correct, but certain linters might get mad at you for creating an anonymous function in a render function (for performance reasons). You also have 2 other options that are more performant.

```
forgetValue = () => {
}
```

or

```
constructor() {
  this.forgetValue = this.forgetValue.bind(this)
}
```

Both will only make one instance of the function that will be used throughout the lifetime of the component. Making a function inside a handler creates a new instance of it each time it rerenders.

Comment: Actually this seems to have worked. I was both binding the method to the constructor and doing the arrow function, which didn't work. I'm curious though why using the method binding does not work...

This solution also prevents me from having to use `this.mounted` at all.

Comment: Use one or the other. I think scoping get wonky when you try to do both